# nodemon show undefined in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I install the first time nodemon and I run npm run start or nodemon filename. I try many cmd but not working [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4swQ.png)

in terminal show below error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E14eT.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E14eT.png)

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
```

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js asyn.js`
after the data
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js asyn.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
after the data
undefined
[nodemon] starting `node index.js asyn.js`
after the data
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js asyn.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
after the data
undefined
[nodemon] starting `node index.js asyn.js`
after the data
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

```js
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.end('hello from the other side ');
});

server.listen(8000,"127.0.0.1",()=>{
    console.log('the port no 8000');
});
```

Comment: what do you get when run this command in cmd  `node index.js`

Comment: sorry for the late when I run direct the code in VSC, not error occurs but in cmd show the following error internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\programs\node js\index.js'       
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}